# How to update a model's class method with form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This may be more of a conceptual issue than a syntactical one, but I would appreciate any input on how to approach the problem. I've been puzzling it over for the past couple of days, and have reached a wall.

Here's a general overview of the situation, and I'll go into more specifics below.

I want a user to be able to input his/her zip code, and then return the weather forecast based on that zipcode.

**This is what I currently have:**

**app/models/forecast.rb** //
gets weather data via HTTParty from external API, and formats XML response into the data that I want.

```
class Forecast < ActiveRecord::Base

        attr_accessor :temperature, :icon

        def initialize
            weather_hash = fetch_forecast 
            weather_values(weather_hash)
        end

        def fetch_forecast
            HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/10cfa1d790a05aa4/hourly/q/19446.xml")
        end

        def weather_values(weather_hash)
            hourly_forecast_response = weather_hash.parsed_response['response']['hourly_forecast']['forecast'].first
            self.temperature = hourly_forecast_response['temp']['english']
            self.icon = hourly_forecast_response['icon_url']
        end
    end
```

**app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb** // provides a form for zip code input at the top, and provides a place to display the information returned from the API at the bottom

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="search-form">

                    <%= form_tag("#", method: "get") do %>
                      <p><%= label_tag(:zipcode, "Zipcode:") %></p>
                      <p><%= text_field_tag(:zipcode, value = 19446) %></p>
                      <p><%= submit_tag("Get Weather Forecast") %></p>
                    <% end %>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 display">
                <div class="display-info">

                    <h1>Forecast Info</h1>
                    <%= @forecast.temperature %></p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**My question is:**

How do I connect the form data from the user to the model?

My best guess is to build a form which instantiates a class of the model, calling the 'fetch_forecast' method with a url based on the user input, something along these lines:

```
def fetch_forecast(input)
    HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/10cfa1d790a05aa4/hourly/q/"+input+".xml")
end
```

However, I have no idea whether this is correct or even possible, and if so, I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Any suggestions or pointers more than welcome, and thank you for your help.

Comment: You will be using ajax, else ypu won't be firing a request to the server. Once you do this, make the request to a route for an action that will call this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models and Views are connected by Controllers (for C in MVC). First of all you need a controller to handle parameters received from form in view and pass them to your model.

It's hard to draw an easy way to do this in your application, because I don't know what other models do you have in it and the general logic. But sketch is this:

If weather service returns forecast as a String you can create Table in your DB to store this forecast data somewhere. Then you'll have model Forecast with attributes: "zip_code", "forecast" which are strings.

After that you need to create a controller - ForecastsController:

```
def new
  @forecast = Forecast.new
end

def create
  @forecast = Forecast.new(forecast_params)
end

def show
  @forecast = Forecast.find(params[:id])
end

private

#please note that here is no 'forecast' attribute
def forecast_params
  params.require(:forecast).permit(:zip_code) 
end

# other standard CRUD methods ommited
```

In your model:

```
class Forecast < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :set_forecast

  protected

  def set_forecast
    self.forecast = # GET your forecast through API with your self.zip, which user already gave you 
  end
end
```

That's all. 
Again: this is a very rough and primitive sketch to show the simplest logic.

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer. Took me a couple days of looking through the documentation until everything clicked properly, but this set me in the right direction. Much appreciated.